# Upload file from one site collection to another in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx-webparts, pnp, reactjs

I have a SPFx solution which have a input tag to upload a file. When I try to upload the file in the same context of the site collection it works fine, but I am not able to get uploaded to different site collection.

Example: <input type=file"/> is used to upload the file in **https://sharepoint.com/sites/test1**. When I try to upload using  **sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl** it works fine within same site collection & file uploaded successfully. But I need to upload the file to **https://sharepoint.com/sites/test2**.
Can anyone please help me with this cross site collection file upload issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample test demo(React framework):

Note: the user should have permission for target site/library.

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" />
<button className="button" onClick={() => this.UploadFile()} >Upload</button>
```

Below is the JS code.

```
protected UploadFile(){
    var files = (document.getElementById('uploadFile') as HTMLInputElement).files;
    
    var file = files[0];
    if (file != undefined || file != null) {
      let spOpts : ISPHttpClientOptions  = {
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: file        
      };

      var url = `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/site/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyDoc')/RootFolder/Files/Add(url='${file.name}', overwrite=true)`

      this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, spOpts).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {

        console.log(`Status code: ${response.status}`);
        console.log(`Status text: ${response.statusText}`);

        response.json().then((responseJSON: JSON) => {
          console.log(responseJSON);
        });
      });

    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, its working fine but how we update the metadata along with file uploaded?

Comment: Need upload the file first, and then update metadata, you could check the logic https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery#code-example-2-upload-a-file-in-the-same-domain-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery (the code might be different, but logic same)

Comment: All works fine, able to upload file and update the metadata, but problem is i am updating this to dropoff library with content organizer rule. Adding the file first and update the metadata did not trigger the content organizer rule. But when i click on edit properties and just submit, content query rule hit and document will be redirected